# How can I remove vue cli 2?

Tags: vue.js, terminal, vue-cli

I want to create a vue project with @vue/cli .

As you know vue/cli update to version 3.

Document says
[image: vue doc]
and I'm in ubuntu 17.10 , try to remove vue-cli with `npm uninstall vue-cli -g` .

But in the terminal I'm only still have access to vue-cli command.

And with `vue --version` still got steel `2.8.2`.

Comment: Try npm uninstall -g @vue/cli? with/without "sudo"

Comment: What happened when you ran the uninstall command?

Comment: unintalled perfectly ... :| but still access to it ! :|

Comment: Is it also installed locally where you are running the unintall? (remove -g from the command)

Comment: Remove your `node_modules` directory after you `uninstall it globally`, then re-install.

Comment: not working at all :(

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I solved the same issue you have (or had), I don't know if you already solved it but here is how I solved it.

using `which vue` I saw where vue was installed.

```
christianjavan@rog:$ which vue
/usr/bin/vue
```

Then I deleted all vue files inside the installation folder

```
christianjavan@rog:/usr/bin$ sudo rm -rf vue
christianjavan@rog:/usr/bin$ sudo rm -rf vue-init
christianjavan@rog:/usr/bin$ sudo rm -rf vue-list
```

Then I did exactly what it says in [this link](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions#option-2-change-npms-default-directory-to-another-directory).

```
christianjavan@rog:/$ mkdir ~/.npm-global
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/christianjavan/.npm-global’: File exists
christianjavan@rog:/$ npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
christianjavan@rog:/$ export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
christianjavan@rog:/$ source ~/.profile
```

Then I tried to install the new vue cli

```
christianjavan@rog:/$ npm install -g @vue/cli
```

Then I did vue --version and finally got the 3.0.3 version installed

```
christianjavan@rog:/$ vue --version
3.0.3
```

I really hope this helps.

NOTE: After trying to run vue -V again later, it did't found the vue command, so I exported the new vue directory to the PATH. When you run `npm install -g @vue/cli` the command gives you the new vue directory.

```
christianjavan@rog:~$ npm install -g @vue/cli
/home/christianjavan/.npm-global/bin/vue -> /home/christianjavan/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/bin/vue.js
```

You add that directory to your PATH.

```
christianjavan@rog:~$ export PATH=$PATH:/home/christianjavan/.npm-global/bin
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias Christian, esta respuesta fue la solucion para mi.  This helped me immensely.

Answer (score 15):

I use `nvm` to switch between node versions. In my case I had installed `vue-cli` on the `system` node and that had been symlinked to `/usr/local/bin/vue`

To fix:

```
nvm use system
npm uninstall -g vue-cli
```

At this point `which vue` should return `vue not found`. In that case you can `nvm use` your desired version and it should run out of that version's directory.

Comment: For those who have nvm installed, especially on a windows machine, use this answer by @GrokSrc. Restart your Git bash, powershell or cmd. Run `vue --version` to check if vue is still installed. You can then install the latest using `npm install -g @vue/cli`

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this will help anyone but

- To uninstall 2.x I had to:

  ```
  npm uninstall -g vue-cli
  ```
- To upgrade to 3.x:

  ```
  npm install -g @vue/cli
  ```

Comment: I think it should be:
npm uninstall -g @vue/cli

Answer (score 2):

**sudo npm uninstall @vue/cli -g**

Comment: Command-only answers are generally frowned upon on this site. Could you please edit your answer to include some comments or explanation of your command? Explanations should answer questions like: What does it do? How does it do it? Where does it go? How does it solve OP's problem? See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to uninstall using the steps below

step 1 -> using '`which vue`' commond to saw where vue was installed.

ex -:

```
kaw@kaw-HP-Notebook:~/script1/Hutch OPS/vue1$ which vue
/usr/local/bin/vue
```

step 2-: go to vue installed location

ex -: `cd /usr/local/bin`

step 3-: Now use following commands to uninstalled the vue

```
sudo rm -rf vue
sudo rm -rf vue-init
sudo rm -rf vue-list
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit, I thought your problem was that you did not know how to uninstall vue-cli 3:

1. Uninstall it globally: `npm uninstall -g vue-cli`
2. Remove local node_modules / `npm uninstall vue-cli`
3. Try reinstall if you want

Comment: try it , same result !

Comment: try reinstalling it and uninstalling it again, maybe you had an old version and you need to do this again.

Comment: This will remove `@vue/cli 3`, while OP wants to remove `vue-cli 2`.

Comment: So I can start using `npx`, I actually wanted to globally uninstall @vue/cli 3 and your original post helped. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows:

Just find out where your vue is located through the command:

`which vue`

Then delete all files with prefix 'vue' (e.g. vue-client, vue.cmd). After that type 'which vue' again and note that the path was changed.

Then, if necessary, install @vue/cli again:

`npm i @vue/cli -g`

Answer (score 0):

At node v10.10.0 and npm 6.4.1 , the following command updated my vue version to 3.4.0

```
sudo npx npm install -g @vue/cli
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed NodeJs in a folder and set the path in `Environmental Variable` to use as normal user ( without Admin rights for setup).

Later when I installed `NodeJS` using setup along with latest `NPM` and `Vue-Cli`, I had to remove the path entry that i set previously to make latest installation effective.

Answer (score 0):

uninstall it first with :- $ npm uninstall vue-cli -g or yarn global remove vue-cli

Install it again using :-
$ npm install -g @vue/cli@latest

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo npm uninstall -g vue-cli
which vue
>> /usr/local/bin/vue
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/vue*
sudo npm install -g @vue/cli
vue --version
>> @vue/cli 4.2.3
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please be careful suggesting the usage of sudo with npm, as there are security implications of running npm with elevated privileges. Answers that consist of a series of commands really benefit from adding an explanation of what each command does, what output to expect, and how to revert the changes of each command should there be a problem with the sequence of commands.